# VirtualStringTree how to free multiple nodes

Tags: delphi-7, virtualtreeview, delphi, tvirtualstringtree

I have a VirtualStringTree with X roots and X childnodes.

Every root has a special NodeData assigned.
Every childnode has another NodeData assigned. 
How do I know OnFreeNode which is which? Cause I can't free the data without knowing which record is assigned to it.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To determine a node level use the `GetNodeLevel` function. It returns the 0 based level index, where 0 means a root node, 1 is for a root's child, 2 is for a root's grandchild etc.

So, in `OnFreeNode` event you can use something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualTreeFreeNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode);
begin
  case VirtualTree.GetNodeLevel(Node) of
    0: // free your root node data
    1: // free your root's child node data
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you. I also forgot that the nodedatasize is a fixed size.